# Issue with DATE_SUB() and MIN()

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to get all the rows from 10 days before the last matching **property_id**.

The query below is what I came up with but the **HAVING** part is not working.

```
SELECT *

FROM tab t

WHERE t.property_id=1
GROUP BY t.property_id
HAVING t.creation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(MIN(t.creation_date), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND MIN(t.creation_date)

ORDER BY t.creation_date DESC
```

It returns all the rows matching **property_id** without checking the date. At first I thought the **HAVING** was ignored but after a few tests, I realized the error was indeed within that very line.

As I could see by modifying my query, the test below worked perfectly :

```
HAVING t.creation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2017-05-29 00:00:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND '2017-05-29 00:00:00'
```

This one too :

```
HAVING t.creation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2017-05-29 00:00:00', INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND MIN(t.creation_date)
```

But not this one :

```
HAVING t.creation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(MIN(t.creation_date), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND '2017-05-29 00:00:00'
```

So as a conclusion, I think the part making the **HAVING** encounters troubles is :

```
DATE_SUB(MIN(t.creation_date), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

- How can that part makes my **HAVING** useless ?
- Is there a reason of why I can't or shouldn't use DATE_SUB() and MIN() together ?
- If so, is there a way to bypass that limitation ?

**EDIT AND ANSWER**

Well following the answer of scaisEdge, and with a bit of modification from my part, the ideal MySQL code for me is the following :

```
SELECT *

    FROM table t

    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(creation_date) AS early_date

            FROM table t
            WHERE t.property_id=1   

    ) AS sub

    WHERE t.property_id= 1 AND t.creation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sub.early_date, INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND sub.early_date
```

I still have some trouble understanding why the **HAVING** was behaving in such away, I will be more wary of him in its use from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a suggestion

Could be you have some issue in data  anyway you can try

in this way. This query  don't use having and and use  only  between on pre calculated  value

```
select * 
FROM tab t
inner join (
  select  DATE_SUB(MIN(t.creation_date), INTERVAL 10 DAY) as min_min , 
                    MIN(t.creation_date) as min_max
  FROM tab t
  WHERE t.property_id=1
) t2  on t.t.creation_date between t2.min_min and t2.min_max
WHERE t.property_id=1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working, it get me all the rows, without checking the t.property or the BETWEEN.

Comment: What kind of data is the creation_date column?

Comment: A Timestamp column

Comment: It's finally working, with a bit of modification from my part though but overall your answer was the one that inspired me. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome .
What was the cause of the problem?

Comment: Don't really now, I tried several times in different ways following your example and at the end I finally did something that was working correctly. But if I may add, I think there is a line wrong in your code, if I'm not mistaken it is not possible to put a WHERE before an INNER JOIN. But I imagine it's just a line you let while modifying my code.

Comment: @Maxime.D  ... yes .. the where was in wrong position ... answer updated .. many thanks